# Entity Framework database connection string and class library without startup project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having a bit of trouble with Entity Framework and class libraries. We already have databases, so I chose to use database first approach to get type safety.

The resulting dll file is supposed to be consumed by another application, which allows creation of custom "agents" in the form of a dll file.

For testing I use PowerShell to instantiate the classes and call their methods.

Now, you might already see the problem. There is no such thing as a startup project. All I have are class libraries to be consumed.

At runtime, EF cannot find app.config file, nor use the connection string therein. Which of course produces following error:

```
Exception calling "GetPersonStaff" with "0" argument(s): "No connection string named 'StaffEntities' could be found in the application config file."
```

Then I tried to explicitly give the class inheriting DbContext a connection string. But that led to following error:

```
Exception calling "GetPersonStaff" with "0" argument(s): "The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This
 will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection st
ring is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and t
hat you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.micros
oft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715"
```

I am kinda stumped now. I tried to google for a solution, but they all either tell me to change startup project, copy app.config/web.config to startup project, or use explicit connection string. None of which are usable in my use case, I believe.

How should I tackle this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured this out. The correct approach is "Code First from Database", which allows explicit connection string to be used.